# YouTube Video Embed iFrame Failing On Membership Videos

Tags: youtube, header, embed

I've posted on YouTubes community page and I've heard nothing back from them so I'm going to see if someone here can help me figure this out.

A few days ago the embedded videos on my website just stopped working: https://enlighten-university.com/course.html.php?active=3

[image: My Websites Error]

At first, I thought it was maybe a problem with my iFrames or an API on the website but when I visited YouTube I discovered the same problem on their website:

[image: YouTubes Error]

So I figured maybe YouTube itself was down but when I checked my other videos, videos that are not a part of my membership program, the embed function seems to work fine.

[image: Works fine]

So then I hit f12 and there I've discovered the problem. The YouTube embed function relies on a header, a Google header, that lets the server know that the person trying to watch the video is in fact a member. Their Google account has to follow them, but for some reason, that header is no longer working.

[image: f12]

Comment: `I've posted on YouTubes community page` = can you add the link of your post in your question? - also, this behavior seems like a bug, my advice is you also post this issue in [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:186600%2B).